# Configuration management based on Python

Tags: python, configuration-management

I am searching a software which does configuration management in python syntax.

Required feature:

- open source (but not GPL)
- Python syntax
- debuggable
- command line tool
- state based (Second call should say "successed: N, changed: 0".)
- exceptions must not get swallowed
- a `--dry-run` option is needed: Nothing gets done, and the tools tells me what would get done.

Background:

In 2013 we switched from shell scripts to fabric to do configuration management. Fabric had the disadvantage that it is not state-based.

In 2014 we switched from farbric to salt-stack.

Now I want to switch from salt-stack to an other solution.
Ansible seems to be the current hype.

But for me every solution which is not python coding feels way to complicated for me.

I wrote a bit about the background here: https://github.com/guettli/yaml-and-Jinja-for-configuration-management